# No system.drawing in .netcore? What to do?

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-core

I'm currently well underway with the conversion of a MVC webapp to a Xamarin app. But it now turns out system.drawing is not supported in .netcore.

```
    public MemoryStream GetGraph_StakeholderMap()
    {
        var smallfont = 20;
        var mediumfont = 25;
        var largefont = 40;

        var width = 1920;
        var height = 1080;

        var blockwidth = 1650;
        var blockheight = 900;

        var arrowoffset = 40;

        var blockleft = 200;
        var blocktop = 50;

        var smallblockwidth = blockwidth / 2;
        var smallblockheight = blockheight / 2;


        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        using (FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial"))
        using (Font fontLarge = new Font(fontFamily, largefont, FontStyle.Regular))
        using (Font fontMedium = new Font(fontFamily, mediumfont, FontStyle.Regular))
        using (Font fontSmall = new Font(fontFamily, smallfont, FontStyle.Regular))
        using (SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(79, 193, 233)))
        using (SolidBrush grayBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray))
        using (SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
        using (StringFormat alignlefttop = new StringFormat())
        using (StringFormat alignleftbottom = new StringFormat())
        using (StringFormat alignrighttop = new StringFormat())
        using (StringFormat alignrightbottom = new StringFormat())
        using (StringFormat alignleft = new StringFormat())
        using (StringFormat aligncenter = new StringFormat())
        using (StringFormat aligncenterhor = new StringFormat())
        using (StringFormat alignright = new StringFormat())
        {
            alignleft.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            alignleft.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

            aligncenter.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            aligncenter.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            aligncenterhor.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            aligncenterhor.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            aligncenterhor.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;

            alignright.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            alignright.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;



            alignlefttop.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            alignlefttop.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

            alignleftbottom.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            alignleftbottom.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

            alignrighttop.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            alignrighttop.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;

            alignrightbottom.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            alignrightbottom.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;

            // Fill
            graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));

            // Achtergrond
            graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, new Rectangle(blockleft, blocktop, smallblockwidth, smallblockheight));
            graphics.FillRectangle(grayBrush, new Rectangle(blockleft + smallblockwidth, blocktop, smallblockwidth, smallblockheight));
            graphics.FillRectangle(grayBrush, new Rectangle(blockleft, blocktop + smallblockheight, smallblockwidth, smallblockheight));
            graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, new Rectangle(blockleft + smallblockwidth, blocktop + smallblockheight, smallblockwidth, smallblockheight));

            // Arrows
            using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 10))
            using (GraphicsPath capPath = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                // A triangle
                capPath.AddLine(-2, 0, 2, 0);
                capPath.AddLine(-2, 0, 0, 2);
                capPath.AddLine(0, 2, 2, 0);
                capPath.AddLine(-2, 0, 2, 0);
                p.CustomEndCap = new CustomLineCap(null, capPath);

                // Y-as arrow
                graphics.DrawLine(p,
                    blockleft - arrowoffset, blocktop + blockheight + arrowoffset,
                    blockleft - arrowoffset, blocktop + 20);

                // X-as arrow
                graphics.DrawLine(p,
                    blockleft - arrowoffset, blocktop + blockheight + arrowoffset,
                    blockleft + blockwidth - 20, blocktop + blockheight + arrowoffset);
            }

            // Y-as
            graphics.DrawString("HIGH", fontSmall, Brushes.Black,
                new Rectangle(0, blocktop, blockleft - arrowoffset * 2, smallfont + 2), alignright);

            graphics.DrawString("LOW", fontSmall, Brushes.Black,
                new Rectangle(0, blocktop + blockheight + arrowoffset * 2, blockleft - arrowoffset * 2, smallfont + 2), alignright);

            graphics.DrawString("POWER", fontMedium, Brushes.Black,
                new Rectangle(0, blocktop, blockleft - arrowoffset * 2, blockheight + 2), aligncenterhor);


            // X-as
            graphics.DrawString("HIGH", fontSmall, Brushes.Black,
                new Rectangle(blockleft, blocktop + blockheight + arrowoffset * 2, blockwidth, smallfont + 2), alignright);

            graphics.DrawString("LEVEL OF INTEREST", fontMedium, Brushes.Black,
                new Rectangle(blockleft, blocktop + blockheight + arrowoffset * 2, blockwidth, height - (blocktop + blockheight + arrowoffset * 2)), aligncenter);



            // Texten
            graphics.DrawString("KEEP SATISFIED", fontSmall, Brushes.Black,
                new Rectangle(blockleft, blocktop, blockwidth, blockheight), alignlefttop);

            graphics.DrawString("KEY PLAYERS", fontSmall, Brushes.Black,
                new Rectangle(blockleft, blocktop, blockwidth, blockheight), alignrighttop);

            graphics.DrawString("MINIMAL EFFORT", fontSmall, Brushes.Black,
                new Rectangle(blockleft, blocktop, blockwidth, blockheight), alignleftbottom);

            graphics.DrawString("KEEP INFORMED", fontSmall, Brushes.Black,
                new Rectangle(blockleft, blocktop, blockwidth, blockheight), alignrightbottom);


            var rect = new Rectangle(blockleft, blocktop, blockwidth, blockheight);
            Draw_Helper.DrawDots(graphics, rect, Stakeholders);


            // Opslaan
            bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        }

        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        return memoryStream;
    }
```

I have about 15 of these functions that compile fine with the system.drawing.commen references. But when I run the code I get this error on the "using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))" part:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'System.Drawing is not supported on this platform.'
```

After searching a lot, it seems there just isn't a solution for this. But I really don't want to have to rewrite all those 15 functions, so does anyone have a good solutions for this?

Comment: SkiaSharp is generally your best bet for cross-platform drawing

Comment: Does the syntax look like the original system.drawing code?

Comment: Scott Hanselman has a [great article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoYouUseSystemDrawingInNETCore.aspx) about this.

Comment: My question is about how to solve this problem without (or with as less as possible) rewriting of those 1000 lines of painting code.

Comment: It's a completely different API.  Unfortunately System.Drawing is old and not easily ported to other platforms.  Skia was designed from the outset to be cross platform.

Comment: This project has been such a blessing :(

Comment: Is this Xamarin or .NET Core? They are two different platforms with two different levels of support for the `System.Drawing` API. If this is .NET Core, what version of .NET Core is this?

Comment: Can you point me out how to see the difference? (kinda new in xamarin) I started a Xamarin project (might have been xamarin forms). I thought xamarin was using .netcore and mono to create a crossplatform solution.

Comment: Now writing my own graphics object btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own library to translate it to a javascript canvas image:

```
public class Graphics
{
    public Graphics(string name, int width, int height)
    {
        Name = name;
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Construct();
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }

    public string Script { get; private set; }

    void Construct()
    {
        Script = "";
        Script += "var c" + Name + " = document.getElementById(\"canvas" + Name + "\");\n";
        Script += "var ctx" + Name + " = c" + Name + ".getContext(\"2d\");\n";
    }

    public void FillRectangle(SolidBrush brush, Rectangle rect)
    {
        FillRectangle(brush, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Width, rect.Height);
    }
    public void FillRectangle(SolidBrush brush, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".fillStyle = \"" + brush.Color.ToRgbaCode() + "\";\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".fillRect(" + x + ", " + y + ", " + width + ", " + height + ");\n";
    }
    internal void DrawLine(Pen pen, Point point1, Point point2)
    {
        DrawLine(pen, point1.X, point1.Y, point2.X, point2.Y);
    }
    public void DrawLine(Pen pen, int x, int y, int x2, int y2)
    {
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".beginPath();";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".strokeStyle = \"" + pen.Color.ToRgbaCode() + "\";\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".lineWidth = \"" + pen.Width + "\";\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".moveTo(" + x + ", " + y + ");\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".lineTo(" + x2 + ", " + y2 + ");\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".stroke();\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".closePath();\n";
    }
    public void DrawArrow(Pen pen, int x, int y, int x2, int y2)
    {
        var headlen = 32; // length of head in pixels
        var dx = x2 - x;
        var dy = y2 - y;
        var angle = Math.Atan2(dy, dx);

        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".beginPath();";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".strokeStyle = \"" + pen.Color.ToRgbaCode() + "\";\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".lineWidth = \"" + pen.Width + "\";\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".moveTo(" + x.ToString("F0") + ", " + y.ToString("F0") + ");\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".lineTo(" + x2.ToString("F0") + ", " + y2.ToString("F0") + ");\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".lineTo(" + (x2 - headlen * Math.Cos(angle - Math.PI / 6)).ToString("F0") + ", " + (y2 - headlen * Math.Sin(angle - Math.PI / 6)).ToString("F0") + ");\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".moveTo(" + x2.ToString("F0") + ", " + y2.ToString("F0") + ");\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".lineTo(" + (x2 - headlen * Math.Cos(angle + Math.PI / 6)).ToString("F0") + ", " + (y2 - headlen * Math.Sin(angle + Math.PI / 6)).ToString("F0") + ");\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".stroke();\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".closePath();\n";
    }
    public void DrawString(string text, Font font, SolidBrush color, Rectangle rectangle, StringFormat format)
    {
        var topoffset = 0;
        if (format.LineAlignment == StringAlignment.Far)
        {
            topoffset = rectangle.Height;
        }
        else if (format.LineAlignment == StringAlignment.Center)
        {
            topoffset = (rectangle.Height - font.Size) / 2 + font.Size;
        }
        else
        {
            topoffset = font.Size;
        }

        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".font = \"" + font.Size + "px " + font.FontFamily.Name + "\";\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".fillStyle = \"" + color.Color.ToRgbaCode() + "\";\n";

        //if (format.FormatFlags == StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical)
        //{
        //    Script += "ctx" + Name + ".rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);\n";
        //}

        if (format.Alignment == StringAlignment.Far)
        {
            // Horizontal Right
            var left = rectangle.Left + rectangle.Width;
            var top = rectangle.Top + topoffset;

            Script += "ctx" + Name + ".textAlign = \"right\";\n";
            Script += "ctx" + Name + ".fillText(\"" + text + "\", \"" + left + "\", \"" + top + "\");\n";
        }
        else if (format.Alignment == StringAlignment.Center)
        {
            // Horizontal Center
            var left = rectangle.Left + rectangle.Width / 2;
            var top = rectangle.Top + topoffset;

            Script += "ctx" + Name + ".textAlign = \"center\";\n";
            Script += "ctx" + Name + ".fillText(\"" + text + "\", \"" + left + "\", \"" + top + "\");\n";
        }
        else
        {
            // Horizontal Left
            var left = rectangle.Left;
            var top = rectangle.Top + topoffset;

            Script += "ctx" + Name + ".textAlign = \"left\";\n";
            Script += "ctx" + Name + ".fillText(\"" + text + "\", \"" + left + "\", \"" + top + "\");\n";
        }

        //if (format.FormatFlags == StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical)
        //{
        //    Script += "ctx" + Name + ".rotate(0);\n";
        //}
    }
    public void DrawRectangle(Pen pen, Rectangle rect)
    {
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".beginPath();\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".lineWidth = \"" + pen.Width + "\";\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".strokeStyle = \"" + pen.Color.ToRgbaCode() + "\";\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".rect(" + rect.Left + ", " + rect.Top + ", " + rect.Width + ", " + rect.Height + ");\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".stroke();\n";
    }
    public void DrawEllipse(Pen pen, double x, double y, double w, double h)
    {
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".beginPath();\n";

        var kappa = .5522848;
        var ox = (w / 2) * kappa; // control point offset horizontal
        var oy = (h / 2) * kappa; // control point offset vertical
        var xe = x + w;           // x-end
        var ye = y + h;           // y-end
        var xm = x + w / 2;       // x-middle
        var ym = y + h / 2;       // y-middle

        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".beginPath();";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".strokeStyle = \"" + pen.Color.ToRgbaCode() + "\";\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".lineWidth = \"" + pen.Width + "\";\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".moveTo(" + x + ", " + ym + ");";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".bezierCurveTo(" + x + ", " + (ym - oy) + ", " + (xm - ox) + ", " + y + ", " + xm + ", " + y + ");";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".bezierCurveTo(" + (xm + ox) + ", " + y + ", " + xe + ", " + (ym - oy) + ", " + xe + ", " + ym + ");";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".bezierCurveTo(" + xe + ", " + (ym + oy) + ", " + (xm + ox) + ", " + ye + ", " + xm + ", " + ye + ");";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".bezierCurveTo(" + (xm - ox) + ", " + ye + ", " + x + ", " + (ym + oy) + ", " + x + ", " + ym + ");";

        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".lineWidth = \"" + pen.Width + "\";\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".strokeStyle = \"" + pen.Color.ToRgbaCode() + "\";\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".stroke();\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".closePath();\n";
    }
    public void FillEllipse(SolidBrush brush, double x, double y, double w, double h)
    {
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".beginPath();\n";

        var kappa = .5522848;
        var ox = (w / 2) * kappa; // control point offset horizontal
        var oy = (h / 2) * kappa; // control point offset vertical
        var xe = x + w;           // x-end
        var ye = y + h;           // y-end
        var xm = x + w / 2;       // x-middle
        var ym = y + h / 2;       // y-middle

        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".beginPath();";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".fillStyle = \"" + brush.Color.ToRgbaCode() + "\";\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".moveTo(" + x + ", " + ym + ");";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".bezierCurveTo(" + x +            ", " + (ym - oy) +  ", " + (xm - ox) +  ", " + y +          ", " + xm +     ", " + y + ");";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".bezierCurveTo(" + (xm + ox) +    ", " + y +          ", " + xe +         ", " + (ym - oy) +  ", " + xe +     ", " + ym + ");";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".bezierCurveTo(" + xe +           ", " + (ym + oy) +  ", " + (xm + ox) +  ", " + ye +         ", " + xm +     ", " + ye + ");";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".bezierCurveTo("+ (xm - ox) +     ", " + ye +         ", " + x +          ", " + (ym + oy) +  ", " + x +      ", " + ym + ");";

        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".fill();\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".closePath();\n";
    }
    public void DrawImage(Image img, Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        Script += "var img" + img.Id + " = new Image;\n";
        Script += "ctx" + Name + ".onload = function() {\n";
        Script += "   ctx" + Name + ".drawImage(img" + img.Id + ", 0, 0);\n";
        Script += "};\n";
        Script += "img" + img.Id + ".src = \"" + img.Url + "\";\n";
    }
}
public static class Brushes
{
    public static SolidBrush Black => new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    public static SolidBrush White => new SolidBrush(Color.White);
}
public class Color
{
    public Color(int a, int r, int g, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }

    public int A { get; private set; }
    public int R { get; private set; }
    public int G { get; private set; }
    public int B { get; private set; }

    public static Color FromArgb(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        return new Color(255, r, g, b);
    }

    public string ToRgbaCode() => "rgba(" + R + ", " + G + ", " + B + ", " + A + ")";

    public static Color LightGray => new Color(255, 192, 192, 192);
    public static Color White => new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
    public static Color Black => new Color(255, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Color LightBlue => new Color(255, 128, 128, 255);
    public static Color DarkBlue => new Color(255, 0, 0, 128);
    public static Color Gray => new Color(255, 128, 128, 128);
    public static Color Green => new Color(255, 0, 255, 0);
}
public class Font : IDisposable
{
    public Font(FontFamily fontFamily, int largefont, FontStyle regular)
    {
        this.FontFamily = fontFamily;
        this.Size = largefont;
        this.FontStyle = regular;
    }

    public FontFamily FontFamily { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public FontStyle FontStyle { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
public class FontFamily : IDisposable
{
    public FontFamily(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
public enum FontStyle
{
    Regular
}
public class Image : IDisposable
{
    static long _Id { get; set; }

    public long Id { get; } = ++_Id;

    public Image(string url)
    {
        this.Url = url;
    }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public static Image FromFile(string url)
    {
        return new Image(url);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
public class Pen : IDisposable
{
    public Pen(SolidBrush black)
    {
        this.Brush = black;
    }
    public Pen(Color color, int width)
    {
        this.Brush = new SolidBrush(color, width);
    }
    public SolidBrush Brush { get; private set; }
    public Color Color => Brush.Color;
    public int Width => Brush.Width;

    public float[] DashPattern { get; internal set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
public class Rectangle
{
    public Rectangle()
    {

    }

    public Rectangle(int left, int top, int width, int height)
    {
        this.Left = left;
        this.Top = top;
        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;
    }

    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Right => Left + Width;
    public int Bottom => Top + Height;
}
public class SolidBrush : IDisposable
{
    public SolidBrush(Color color, int width = 1)
    {
        this.Color = color;
        this.Width = width;
    }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
public enum StringAlignment
{
    Near,
    Center,
    Far
}
public class StringFormat : IDisposable
{
    public StringAlignment LineAlignment { get; set; } = StringAlignment.Near;
    public StringAlignment Alignment { get; set; } = StringAlignment.Near;
    public StringFormatFlags FormatFlags { get; set; } = StringFormatFlags.DirectionHorizontal;

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
public enum StringFormatFlags
{
    DirectionHorizontal,
    DirectionVertical
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Aspose.Drawing](https://products.aspose.com/drawing/net) as a cross-platform drop-in replacement for System.Drawing.Common. It provides fully compatible API so that you don't have to change your existing code. (I'm one of the developers.)